# In the morning, yesterday, in the evening, two days ago

Tags: grammar

Should such word order be avoided by learners of English and is the comma required after each time phrase?

1. "Two days ago, I bought an interesting book",
2. "In the morning, I bought a newspaper".
3. "Yesterday, I met her on my way home".
4. "In the evening, I read a newspaper."

Comment: The comma is optional. Introduce it if you think the sentence would read better with a pause at that point - or if it makes the sentence clearer (which it doesn't here).  If the time/period is what you want to emphasise, by all means begin the sentence with it.

Comment: There is no reason for you to avoid this usage, if you want to emphasise the time rather than the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules of punctuation are not rules of grammar, but are specified as rules in style guides. Most style guides, however, agree on most issues.

A very general rule about commas is that they should be used where a brief pause would occur in a spoken sentence.

In speech, adverbial words or phrases modifying the verb and preceding the subject are usually followed by a pause. I guess the reason is that a pause provides time for the listener to realize that the most frequent word order is not being followed.

> Yesterday was rainy.

“Yesterday” is being used here as a noun, is the subject of the sentence, and is not followed by a pause in speech.

> Yesterday, the bakery at the corner of Maple and Broad streets burned down.

“Yesterday” is being used here as an adverb of time, is not the subject, and is normally followed by a pause. I’d indicate the pause in writing with a comma.

Notice that

> The bakery at the corner of Maple and Broad streets burned down yesterday

likewise uses “yesterday” as an adverb of time, but the structure of the sentence is the ubiquitous subject, verb, adverb, and there is no pause in speech between “burned down” and “yesterday.” Nor should there be a comma between them in writing.

As I said before, the rules on punctuation are not uniform. But I doubt that anyone will object if, when writing a sentence that starts with a subordinate clause or adverbial word or phrase, you always follow it with a comma.